# Blocking "hacking" attempts via .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to block request been made to our pagination parameter by multiple robots (evil ones it seems)

Hundreds of these types of requests are showing up:

http://www.ourdomain.com/search.php?q=search+query&page=366100876

Is there a way using regular expressions in .htaccess to send any request that requests a page larger than 1000 or anything more than 4 digits in the parameter 'page' ?

'q' parameter is of course always different.

Thank you.

Comment: By requests a page larger than 1000 do you mean requests from URLs larger than 1000 characters?

Comment: I think he means `&page=1000` as the max value.  (Vote to migrate to SF?)

Comment: any number larger than 1000 asked for the [page] parameter should be redirected to /error500.html

Answer (score 0):

I derived most of this from a really cool article called [Ultimate .htaccess file sample](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/ultimate-htaccess-file-sample.html). Very handy.

```
 Redirect 500 /error500.html

 RedirectMatch 500 ^.+{1001}.+$
```

That would send away any long URLs.

```
 LimitRequestBody 102400
```

That would limit any requests over 100K.

To target the GET variable `page` specifically:

```
RedirectMatch 500 ^.+page=[0-9]{4}.+$
```

Comment: I tried :

RewriteEngine on
RedirectMatch 403 ^.+page=[0-9]{4}.+$

Requested the URL - http://www.ourdomain.com/search.php?q=search+query&page=36666

It didn't redirect to the server 403 error page

Comment: Is `=` part of regex syntax? I'm not sure, honestly. 1) You don't need Rewrite Engine on. This rule allows you to use regex without it. 2) Try escaping out the `=`, so : `RedirectMatch 500 ^.+page\=[0-9]{4}.?$`. The `?` at the end will make it so that the URL can end right after a number between 1000 and 9999

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it works, added it to some other checks I had:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=[0-9]{4} [OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode crap to send via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Send all blocked request to homepage with 403 Forbidden error!
```

Comment: Simon, welcome to SO. You can mask code using the "code" button in the editor, otherwise the hashes get interpreted as `<h1>` titles :)

Answer (score 0):

A: htaccess: `Rewrite, URI /*admin*/* [NC,OR]` - you *must* rename anything with "admin" in it to something else, xyzzy, spot, nancy, fuivan...  This also includes names like login.php become jumpjoy.php.

B: When you see a attempted hack - 188 hits from a non-RU, non-CH IP - contact the hosting company and tell them.  More often than not you get back "Thank you, we have found and cleaned out the bot.[banned the user]"

I never display "403 forbidden", I redirect to some other page (I have a random selection of 7).  I then append htaccess with "deny from $IP".  I host local groups and businesses so there is no need for Ivan wanting a cab... he couldn't afford the fare :-/  There are 900+ deny from in my htaccess.

I run a crontab "find $HOME -newer lasttime | mail-me ; touch lasttime".  That way if anyone does get in I know within a couple of hours.  Also "chmod 444 [all].php".